# Will I be penalised for using two H1 tags in a Bootstrap 3 layout?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, seo, twitter-bootstrap-3

I recently had to build a responsive site where the product page had the following behaviour:

**Extra Small Devices**

H1 occupies own row and below it sits product image (3 columns), followed by product price and other information to the right (9 columns)

**Medium Devices and Above**

H1 sits to the right of the product image as well (so at the top of the 9 column div outlined above).

The only way I managed to get this to behave correctly across the devices I needed it to was as follows:

`<h1 class="visible-xs">Product Name</h1><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-3"><img /></div><div class="col-xs-9"><h1 class="hidden-xs">Product Name</h1>£11.99 and other product info</div></div>`

This means I have 2 H1 tags - is this a problem for SEO or are modern search engines smart enough to understand this?

I tried using col-[size]-push-* and col-[size]-pull-* classes on h1 and image container, but this resulted in the product information container getting treated as a whole new row and coming under the image container & H1.

Sorry - hope that explanation is clear! If anyone knows a better way to do the above and achieve the same result with only one H1 tag that would be most welcome - the bootstrap examples for column ordering are all within the same row, so don't really help in this situation.

Comment: Your question isn't clear- are you worried search engines won't crawl your site because you have two H1 tags?

Comment: MattCutts - More than one H1 on a page: good or bad?: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIn5qJKU8VM‎

Comment: @Reeno - it's more than the fact that it's one more, it's that it's a duplicate.

Comment: @DaveSwersky No I'm sure they'll crawl it, I'm asking if i'd be penalised for it or are they smart enough to see that only one of them is visible to the user at any time depending on their device?

Comment: There are *so* many search engines, and they all work differently. I’d say the search engine part of your question is off-topic on SO.

Comment: How is it off topic? He is asking if there are any penalties in search engine rankings for having duplicate `h1`s. If anything, the Bootstrap tags are what are off topic, as you would probably have to format the code the same way regardless of the framework to achieve the layout, and thus still have the same question.

Comment: The h1 element does need two tags, a start tag and an end tag. If you use only one, the HTML is invalid. </pedantic>

Answer (score 0):

Based on some [quick](http://www.seounique.com/blog/multiple-h1-tags-triggers-google-penalty/) [research](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/3-commonly-overlooked-wordpress-seo-tweaks/), it would seem that multiple `h1` tags can result in a penalty, at least with Google.

One possible solution is to create an `.h1` class that matches the styles that `h1` has. Then, taking the code you included, you would do this:

```
<h1 class="visible-xs">Product Name</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"><img /></div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <p class="h1 hidden-xs">Product Name</p>
        £11.99 and other product info
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that I replaced the second `h1` tag with a `p` tag, and applied the `.h1` class to it. This should give you the look you are going for while eliminating the duplicate headers.